# Structure of diamond

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, crystal-structure, solid-state-chemistry

"diamond structure. Every carbon atom is bonded
to four other carbon atoms forming a three-dimensional lattice of chair conformations."

SENTENCE FROM A BOOK

What does this mean? 
Where I am struck is that I knew carbons occupy zinc blende like lattice so, how can this line be true.

Answer (score 2):

> Where I am struck is that I knew carbons occupy zinc sulfide like
>   lattice so, how can this line be true.

Zinc sulfide can exist in two different crystalline forms, Zincblende (sphalerite) and wurtzite.  Zincblende is face-centered cubic (also known as diamond cubic), each ion is tetracoordinate and has local tetrahedral geometry - just like the carbons in diamond.  The wurtzite structure is hexagonal close-packed with interconnected 6-membered rings.  You may have been thinking of the wurtzite structure, while it is the zincblende structure that is related to diamond.  You can see pictures of the two structures [here](https://www.princeton.edu/~maelabs/mae324/glos324/zns.htm).

Comment: YES I TO KNOW IT IS ZINC BLENDE  STRUCTURE . BUT, THE BOOK SAYS "Every carbon atom is bonded to four other carbon atoms forming a three-dimensional lattice of chair conformations"

Comment: If you know the fcc structure, maybe you should be more specific what you cannot understand.

Comment: well what is this "chair conformation" related to to diamond structure. I know chair conformation are for hexane . But how does diamond form this structure

Comment: Take a look at the link in my answer and look at the picture for the wurtzite structure - do you see the chair arrangement of the carbon atoms?  If not, here is another link with a good picture of the chair arrangement http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00721087#page-1  When 6 sp3 carbons are placed in a ring, the chair arrangement is a low energy arrangement, no matter whether those carbons are bonded to hydrogen atoms (cyclohexane) or other carbon atoms (diamond).